# Pooling DB Context for .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, dbcontext

I want to make db context to pool but it gives me an error for .net core 3.1.

Error message: The DbContext of type 'MyContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.

I can do it for .net core 2.2 and .net 5 but for .net core 3.1 it gives me the error.

Here is some sample codes that I tried:
Code 1:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(options => 
    options.UseMySql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONN")));
   }
```

Code 2:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONN"));
                optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });
}
```

Constructor of MyContext is:

```
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
{
Database.SetCommandTimeout(9000);
_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Comment: Are you using DB first ?

Comment: I am using code first. @ChinmayT

Comment: how many constructor of MyContext you are having. I would recommend to used 'public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { Database.SetCommandTimeout(9000);}' as public constructor and make all other constructor as private or remove all for test and then add those as private.

Comment: Review this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/#dbcontext-pooling